# "I discover this singer" or "I found out this singer" or "I discover this singer"

Tags: grammar, difference, sentence-choice

I want to tell about a singer who already was famous but I haven't listened before last nigth ... and by casualty I heard when somebody played her

Comment: "I've just discovered this singer". (NB _Casualty_ doesn't mean _chance_ in English.)

Comment: It happened in the past, so you use past tense, not "I discover". Why do you have "found" in the past tense but "discover" in the present?

Comment: I concur with @StuartF.  You're asking for help with three choices that differ in both tense and vocabulary.  It's therefore not clear whether you need help with one of those elements or both of them.  In addition, you've asked about three choices, but the first and third are the same.  I suppose that was a mistake.  Maybe if there were three distinct choices the nature of your question would be clearer.  Can you edit it to correct the title and perhaps add to the body a brief statement of the reason you're uncertain?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the OP intends to say "accident", not "casualty".

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore - Apparently the Spanish word _casualidad_ means 'chance, accident, coincidence'.

Answer (score 1):

You would say:

> I just discovered this singer.

(British English speakers might prefer the present perfect "I've just discovered.")